# Show / load React.js Component dynamically onClick with Navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, components, state, reactjs

I want to load my react component pages dynamically into my main `App.js` Component.

I am not really sure the best way to go about doing this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```html
<app
  <navbar> ... </navbar>

  <React Component Page1 />
  <React Component Page2 />

  <footer> ... </footer>
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, where you want to use a navigation bar, I suggest you get familiar with React Router that contains Link, Switch and Router. 
This might be a good start:
[Using React router](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_router.htm)